# Intent.ACTION_VIEW for Android Image

Tags: android, android-intent, share

[image]

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(
                            Uri.parse("file://" +file.getAbsolutePath()),"image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

I want to display image with share, delete and set as functionality using android intent . but my image is opening without share option......... How to show image with share options?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

By Default it wont show the options with share and delete. But You can do this manually with Intent and File.

Comment: i can do by manually using share Intent.ACTION_SEND but wants default feature, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try following code for share image

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: I know about share Intent.ACTION_SEND intent ... but i want to use both (Image viwer and share feature)